# Transaction cost exceeds current gas limit. (Take II)

Tags: parity, private-blockchain, gas-limit, genesis

I am working on a private blockchain using Parity.  I have changed the gasLimit parameter to read "4712388" instead of the default (0x1388) and when I try to truffle migrate a contract, I get this error:

> [-32010] Transaction cost exceeds current gas limit. Limit: 4700036,
>   got: 4712388. Try decreasing supplied gas.

**Q1: Where does this 4700036 value come from?  Be specific.  What actual chain spec parameter handles this?**

**Q2: Can you confirm that this is taken from a different place than the gasLimit parameter, which is set to 4712388?**

EDIT: Weeks, later, I have a new issue.  It's possible this relates to my other question:

[Why would gasLimit be read as 4,700,036 instead of 4,712,388?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29680/why-would-gaslimit-be-read-as-4-700-036-instead-of-4-712-388)

Answer (score 2):

The genesis.json file provides the initial gas limit for the first block in the chain, but this can be adjusted a little bit with each block. By default Parity gradually adjusts in line with the amount of gas actually used in transactions, so if you have a barely-used private chain it will keep decreasing.

To prevent it dropping below 4712388, run Parity with `--gas-floor-target 4712388`.

Comment: This error is happening on the first transaction, and it still happens with the "--gas-floor-target 4712388" parameter on the command line.  But thank you for trying.

Comment: What do you see when you connect to your blockchain over RPC and look at the current block with `web3.eth.getBlock('latest')`? You should see the block gas limit in the `gasLimit` parameter. Compare this to an earlier block and see if it's changing. Also, try stopping your blockchain and make sure truffle gives you a different error, to prove that truffle is connecting to the blockchain you think it's connecting to.

Comment: I do get a different error if Parity is not running: "Could not connect to your Ethereum client."  When I use web3 I get the following: 
> web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }

Does not look good but I don't know what any of those things mean so not sure where to start.

Comment: I have been reading about "--gas-floor-target" and it looks like that is a command for a Parity node that is running a miner.  Is that correct?