# Why would gasLimit be read as 4,700,036 instead of 4,712,388?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, gas-limit

I have the Block Gas Limit of a private Parity-based blockchain set to 4,712,388.  That's the "gasLimit" parameter.  But when I view it on a block explorer on the very first block running on this network, it reads it as 4,700,036.  That is a factor of 1.0026281/

And when I set it as 44,712,388, it reads in as 44,364,406.  That is a factor of 1.0078437.  So it's not consistent.

There must be some reason though.  Right?

Comment: I awared the bounty to @Linmao_Song but the site keeps saying I didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, Parity rounds the block gas limit value to multiplies of a constant (A follow-up question would be "why?". I can't find the answer yet. It probably should be a separate question anyway). See [this comment](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/1b8f299df2e6a29738a090c47911cc218db49b8d/ethcore/src/machine.rs#L41) in its source code. At the moment, the constant (i.e. see the next line - PARITY_GAS_LIMIT_DETERMINANT) is 37. And the two actual values in the question are both multiplies of 37.

```
4,700,036 = 37 * 127,028
44,364,406 = 37 * 1,199,038
```

Naturally one would notice the rounding result could have been closer to the original value `44,712,388`. It turns out the rounding also takes into account another factor, i.e. a desired range, which is determined by the preceding blocks. See [function round_block_gas_limit](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/1b8f299df2e6a29738a090c47911cc218db49b8d/ethcore/src/machine.rs#L476). This is the reason why it's not consistent.